# Checking if array is empty or not doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, arrays

Simple array and simple check if is array or object .. yet page crashing when there is no array data instead of showing `No`. This is the array

```
$url=get_curl_content_tx("https://example.com");

$arr = json_decode($url, true);     
if (is_array($arr['outputs']) || is_object($arr['outputs'])) {
         echo 'Yes';
} 
else { 
         echo 'No';
}
```

if I receive `fail` i.e. no data from the url and `$arr['outputs']` is empty I've got blank page with

> Undefined index: outputs

instead of `No`. Doesn't `if (is_array($arr['outputs']) || is_object($arr['outputs']))` check if is array or no?

If there is data in `$arr['outputs']` everything is fine.

Comment: Try using `empty()` php function

Comment: Thanks' but same thing with `empty()` .. `isset()` seems to work.

Comment: Does the $arr variable hold what you think it holds?  var_dump ($arr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `isset` or `array_key_exists` to check the key exists in the `$arr` array before referring to it.

```
if (isset($arr['outputs']) && is_array($arr['outputs'])) {
```

Comment: Hm.. interesting. Like this it is working normally. Why isset works but is_array only doesn't work? Do I need also this `is_object()`? Normally I don't expect to be object..

Comment: You're referring to _object_ in your array, but this doesn't exist. You get an error, no matter what function you are using.

Comment: @JasonPaddle run `var_dump($arr['outputs'])`.  It most likely isn't an array or object...  `is_array($arr)` might work, but that isn't the same as `is_array($arr['outputs'])`

Comment: when `$arr['outputs']` is empty i.e. `array ( [status] => fail )` i've got blank page

Answer (score 1):

You want to access a non-existent array, which gives you an error, no matter what function you are using right before. To solve this, check first if the array exists with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($arr)) {
   // Just gets executed if the array exists ans isn't nulll
} else {
   // Array is null or non-existend
}
```

and add then your code in the `if-else`.